# Ошибка при вызове startActivityForResult() из адаптера

Tags: java, android, activity, adapter

При вызова метода `startActivityForResult()` из собственного адаптера выводится ошибка

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: ilhom4ik_app.com.girbar, PID: 9561
                  java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
                      at ilhom4ik_app.com.girbar.ItemsAdapter$1.onClick(ItemsAdapter.java:65)
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Вызываю активити из адаптера вот так

```
holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent item = new Intent(mContext,ItemActivity_level1.class);
                item.putExtra("item",itemList.getUrl());
                item.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                Activity activity = (Activity) mContext;
                activity.startActivityForResult(item,1);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Уточните каким образом вы передаете mContext в адаптер?

Comment: adapter = new ItemsAdapter(listItems, getApplicationContext());

Comment: Ну да, я верно предположил. Вы передаете контекст приложения, а нужно передавать контекст активити.

Comment: Спасибо сработало

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Похоже, вы передаете просто this из вашей активити в адаптер, а нужно передавать ActivityName.this, чтобы передать контекст активити, а не контекст приложения в адаптер.
UPD: вместо getApplicationContext() нужно передавать _имя_активности_.this

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ ! Работает !